# Why can't my boss see the Sourcing Center in Lightning?

Tags: lightning-experience, tab, salesforce-classic

Screenshot from Jobscience Helpdesk
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/gBmW9.png)

My boss thought she was having a Bullhorn/Jobscience problem.  She said she is unable to perform board searches in JobScience in Lightning because the Sourcing Center -- the primary tool for searching for candidates -- does not appear in her Lightning interface.

I contacted Bullhorn/Jobscience and their tech sent me the attached image.  As you can see; in the top right of the image, the Sourcing Center tag does appear in his instance of Lightning.

So my question is, for what reason would my boss be able to see and use the Sourcing Center tab in Classic, but not be able to find it when she toggles to Lightning?

I wanted to try it on my instance.  But even though I selected to add the Sourcing Center tab to my header, it  doesnt apear for me in Classic or Lightning.

What might be causing this?

Comment: `But even though I selected to add the Sourcing Center tag to my header,` - Where did you select to add ?

Comment: From home:  plus symbol - add tab hyperlink

Comment: Salesforce-sas, more important than how I added the tab, is how should I have added the sourcing center tab? It could be that I'm just doing it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure sure what you meant by `plus` sign in Home but pls try below:

Option 1: Click on `pen` symbol at top right:

[image]

Now select `All` from left pane and search for tab and click `Add 1 Nav item` after selecting your tab

[image]

---

Option 2: Click on the 9 dots (Its called App Launcher):

[image]

Now search for tab and click on it

[image]

**------ added based on comments --------**

May be the pencil icon is not visible for a specific app:
Do the following:

From Setup in Lightning Experiance,

Go to App Manager.

Edit your desired app, select App Options.

Enable (uncheck) the checkbox for "Disable end user personalization of nav items in this app".

[image]

**------- added -------**

Go to visualforce pages in setup and check if its `Available for lightning experiance` as shown below:

[image]

**Apart from above, you can also check if your profile has the access to visualforce page.** For this go to your profile and go to visualforce page accesses and check.